# How to generate an aggregated scaladoc for a maven site?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-site-plugin, scala-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven build and I would like to generate an aggregated Scaladoc in my root module, similar to what the aggregate goal for the maven-javadoc-plugin does. My first attempt was:

```
<project ...>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>doc</report>
                                </reports>
                                <configuration>
                                    <aggregateDirectOnly>false</aggregateDirectOnly>
                                    <sendJavaToScalac>false</sendJavaToScalac>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>aggregate</report>
                                </reports>
                            </plugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

However, the aggregateDirectOnly property does not seem to have any effect. I always get the Scaladoc for the individual jar-type POMs only.

I also tried to set forceAggregate to true, but it had no effect, too.

How to do this?

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer the question *exactly* as asked, but is a solution that may actually be preferred for mixed java/scala projects until ScalaDoc is capable of parsing JavaDoc comments. It produces a single aggregated JavaDoc that *includes documentation from all of the project's Scala source files as well*.

The solution is simple: configure Maven to use the [GenJavaDoc](https://github.com/typesafehub/genjavadoc) Scala compiler plugin so that ScalaDocs can be converted to JavaDocs. Then, use the normal `javadoc:aggregate` goal to aggregate the project as normal.

Here is a sample Maven profile to do this. It configures the Scala compiler to generate the JavaDocs corresponding to the Scala sources, configures Maven to treat the `genjavadoc` directory created by the Scala compiler as a source directory, and then configures the javadoc plugin itself (this last may be optional if you have no special JavaDoc plugin configuration requirements).

```xml
<profile>
  <id>javadoc</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>doc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-P:genjavadoc:out=${project.build.directory}/genjavadoc</arg>
          </args>
          <compilerPlugins>
            <compilerPlugin>
              <groupId>com.typesafe.genjavadoc</groupId>
              <artifactId>genjavadoc-plugin_${scala.binary.full.version}</artifactId>
              <version>0.4</version>
            </compilerPlugin>
          </compilerPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/genjavadoc</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <minmemory>64m</minmemory>
          <maxmemory>2g</maxmemory>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
          <detectLinks>true</detectLinks>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: should this be on the reactor pom.xml ?

Comment: @DavidH It should in the POM at the level at which you want to generate the docs for that module and submodules. Don't forget to use the `-Pjavadoc` to enable the profile, or make it your default configuration by putting it in the `build` section directly instead of `profile/build`.

Comment: i am familiar with maven. but i dont understand how to organize the build.
lets say you have 3 modules A,B,C 
Dependency is like that A<-B<-C 
project D is the reactor for A,B,C (A,B,C are modules at D) 
should i create module E for generating scaladoc ? 
where should i put the scaladoc generation ? should it be at C module?

Comment: This only generates the JavaDoc which isn't very useful for Scala code (it shows all the compiler generated classes as well.) Is there a way to generate and aggregate proper ScalaDocs with Maven?

Comment: @DavidH Put it in module D.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen Not as far as I know. As mentioned in the answer, ScalaDoc really needs to learn how to parse and document JavaDoc.

Comment: @Raman In our instance it already shows classes defined in Java together with their JavaDoc. What I need is to be able to aggregate all the scaladocs in my seperate modules into a single scaladoc.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen Ok, it needs to learn how to do that too :-) Last time I looked at this (which was admittedly over a year ago) I couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: so, do we have any final thought of how to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, scaladoc-specific stuff such as `@tparam` makes this approach fail.

Comment: Somehow my generated code from this is conflicting with actual source code: `[ERROR] /home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar-core-services/services-core/target/genjavadoc/edu/cornell/ncrn/ced2ar/service/ApiInfoService.java:8: error: Companions 'class ApiInfoService' and 'object ApiInfoService' must be defined in same file:
[INFO]   Found in /home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar-core-services/services-core/src/main/java/edu/cornell/ncrn/ced2ar/service/ApiInfoService.scala and /home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar-core-services/services-core/target/genjavadoc/edu/cornell/ncrn/ced2ar/service/ApiInfoService.java`