# multi module aggregation for scaladoc in maven

Tags: scala, maven-3, scaladoc, scala-maven-plugin

I have a parent project with 5 modules.  I am trying to figure out how to aggregate the module level scaladoc's into one cohesive site.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301620/how-to-generate-an-aggregated-scaladoc-for-a-maven-site

Comment: The linked question does not have any answers either...

Comment: Agreed. But that doesn't mean it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: The other question is more clear, you should probably put your bounty there and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with SBT by integrationg 'Unidoc' into your build:

- https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/Unidoc.scala

The maven plugin for scala support aggregation too, but by default only direct module, you can change the default behavior (aggregateDirectOnly, forceAggregate):

- http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/doc-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's no farther than I have gotten with simple google searches.  Clearly it's possible, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the scala maven plugin to do it.  To get the 100 bounty, I need a sample pom that clearly shows how it all works.  In the mean time, I have a workaround that isn't terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Scaladoc2 doesn't support aggregation from multi source/multi classpath (scaladoc run over scalac, so aggregation means a full compilation like if there one big project).
And the scala-maven-plugin is mainly a wrapper of the scala commands.

Aggregation is only available to vscaladoc, who is now abandonned.

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If aggregating Scala documentation into the overall Java project documentation is an option, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288487/430128.